# UMVUE for $g(\theta)=\theta^2$ of Poisson random variables

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, umvue

Let $X_1,...X_n$i.i.d.~$Pois(\theta)$ with unknown $\theta>0$, I want to find the UMVUE for $g(\theta)=\theta^2$.

I know that $T(x)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ is complete and sufficient for $\theta>0$.

$\mathbf{E}_\theta[T(x)]=\mathbf{E}_\theta[\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}x_i]=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{E}_\theta[x_i]=n\theta$

$\mathbf{E}_\theta[T(x)^2]=\mathbf{Var}[T(x)]+\mathbf{E}_\theta[T(x)]^2=n\theta+n^2\theta^2$

Hence $\frac{\mathbf{E}_\theta[T(x)^2]-\mathbf{E}_\theta[T(x)]}{n^2}=\theta^2=g(\theta)$

So is $\frac{T(x)^2-T(x)}{n^2}$ the UMVUE for $g(\theta)=\theta^2$?

Comment: Are $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ independent?

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes, thanks for pointing that out, I will make an edit to the quesion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  To make it rigorous, you can apply [Lehmann–Scheffé Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem) with $Y = T(X)$ and $\varphi(Y) = \frac{1}{n^2}(Y^2 - Y)$.

---

After a closer look at the Wikipedia link above, it seems to confuse $\theta$ with $g(\theta)$.  To avoid such ambiguity, I am quoting Theorem 1.1 in *Theory of Point Estimation* by E. Lehmann and G. Casella below.

> Let $X$ be distributed according to a distribution in
> $\mathcal{P} = \{P_\theta, \theta \in \Omega\}$, and suppose $T$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\mathcal{P}$.
>
> (a) For every $U$-estimable function $g(\theta)$, there exists an
> unbiased estimator that uniformly minimizes the risk for any loss
> function $L(\theta, d)$ which is convex in its second argument;
> therefore, this estimator in particular is UMVU.
>
> (b) The UMVU estimator of (a) is the unique unbiased estimator which
> is a function of $T$; it is the unique unbiased estimator with minimum
> risk, provided its risk is finite and $L$ is strictly convex in $d$.

The author also gave the following procedure for determining the UMVUE, which you can directly harness for your problem:

> If $T$ is a complete sufficient statistic, the UMVU estimator of any $U$-estimable function $g(\theta)$ is uniquely determined by the set of equations
> \begin{align}
> E_\theta\delta(T) = g(\theta) \quad \text{for all } \theta \in \Omega.
> \end{align}